# Unordered list not displaying properly

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP problem that requires me to display my name and an unordered list of the first ten perfect squares. Here is the code I was given:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Your Name</p>
<ul>
<li>0</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>16</li>
<li>25</li>
<li>36</li>
<li>49</li>
<li>64</li>
<li>81</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code I've produced:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo '<p>Your Name</p>'; ?>
<ul>
<?
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
        echo ('<li>');
        echo ($i * $i);
        echo ('</li');
    }
?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And the output is:

Your Name

```
'; ?>
'); echo ($i * $i); echo (''); } ?>
```

So what is my issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FerozAkbar is correct. <?php

Comment: syntax error `echo ('</li');` if that's your real code.

Comment: You guys are correct on both but it makes the issue worse.

Comment: now there's a first ^

Comment: As far as the output anyways

Comment: you need to edit your question with what you're now getting as a result and what you expecting as a result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90037/discussion-between-youngmogul-and-fred-ii).

Comment: my take on this is this: You don't have a webserver/PHP/Apache installed or isn't properly configured. Or, you're trying to access it as `file:///file.php` rather than `http://localhost/file.php` I am pretty sure I am right on this. Or not a `.php` extension.

Comment: @YoungMogul I am not kicking for points here, but rather for you to see what I have written in an answer that I have posted below. If that still doesn't work and isn't the solution to all this, then you will need to provide us with more information, such as where you are trying to execute this from, local machine or hosted service.

Comment: I've confirmed I'm accessing it as file://file.php but how do I fix that? I have a webserver installed.

Comment: consult my answer @YoungMogul

Comment: @YoungMogul so, where are we the question? no word from you. I believe I have outlined what the issues are in my answer. If that did not solve the question, then you will need to let me know what's "not" happening. Read my answer in its entirety. If it did solve it, then mark it as solved.

Comment: I was trying to message you through the chat but I guess I didn't get through. My questions is: i've tried accessing it through the localhost but all it says is object not found
so is this a configuration problem?

Comment: yes it is a configuration issue and that is beyond the scope of this question. I believe I already answered the initial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *You guys are correct on both but it makes the issue worse. –  YoungMogul 17 mins ago*

I'm making this comment an answer, along with more information:

My take on this is this: You may not have a webserver/PHP/Apache installed or isn't properly configured. Or, you're trying to access it as `file:///file.php`
rather than `http://localhost/file.php` I am pretty sure I am right on this, or you are not using `.php` extension or haven't instructed Apache to treal `.html` files as PHP if this should be the case.

> *I've confirmed I'm accessing it as file://file.php but how do I fix that? –  YoungMogul 27 secs ago*

By using `http://localhost/file.php`

- Accessing `file:///file.php` via your browser will only parse raw HTML and not PHP directives.
- Oh, that is besides the syntax error already outlined.

**PHP is not being parsed** properly and does not by default during a PHP installation.

That is why you are being shown "code" rather than actual parsed directives.

OP:

```
And the output is:
Your Name
    '; ?>
    '); echo ($i * $i); echo (''); } ?>
```

However, if PHP is in fact running and that you have enable short tags, you need to restart all services before those changes will take effect.

Otherwise, `<?` to `<?php`.

- If on a hosted service, then contact tech support.
- If on a local machine, check your configuration.

**NOTA:** If PHP/Apache/Webserver are not installed, then it will be of no use until you do.

There are a few out there and depending on your environment:

- LAMP
- MAMP
- Xampp
- WAMPserver
- etc.

---

**Local test:**

Which I can confirm the following from HTML source and fixing the syntax error in `echo ('</li');`:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Your Name</p><ul>
<li>0</li><li>1</li><li>4</li><li>9</li><li>16</li><li>25</li><li>36</li><li>49</li><li>64</li><li>81</li></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Using the following source code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo '<p>Your Name</p>'; ?>
<ul>
<?
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
        echo ('<li>');
        echo ($i * $i);
        echo ('</li>');
    }
?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice pick up **access it as file:///file.php
rather than http://localhost/file.php**

Comment: @Saty Yeah, that was the clincher there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors. Use `<?php` instead `<?`  and `echo ('</li>');`instead `echo ('</li');`

Comment: The first one isn't an "error", it's a coding "style" option. The second stands at being a typo, which is why I posted a "comment" about it. However, you stand at being totally correct.

Comment: @Fred-ii-   I am just beginner.. Long way remaining to become professional..  :)

Comment: as every seasoned coder once was ;-) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This error seem like your `short_open_tag` not open in your `php.ini` file

Set

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in php.ini

And restart your Apache server.

OR 
change `<? to <?php`

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
        echo ('<li>');
        echo ($i * $i);
        echo ('</li>');// change `('</li');` to ` ('</li>');`
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just retype your php code as:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo '<p>Your Name</p>'; ?>
<ul>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    echo ('<li>');
    echo ($i * $i);
    echo ('</li');
}
?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```